# Google Spreadsheets: uppercase all words in a cell with more than three characters

Tags: google-sheets

I need to uppercase all words in a cell with more than three characters.

Let's say the cell A1 is `this is a text`

If I use this formula `=proper(A1)` I get this `This Is A Text`

I need a formula to avoid to uppercase words with less than three character, so that I can get this: `This is a Text`.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you

```
=ArrayFormula(join(" ", if(len(split(A1, " "))<3, split(A1, " "), proper(split(A1," ")))))
```